# Can I add content in an org file that is under a heading that isn't part of that heading

Tags: org-mode

Is there a way to add content below a heading, but signal to orgmode that the content should be at the root scope and not under that heading?

Basically something like this:

```
This is something at the root of the file
* Heading 1
  Content under heading 1
* Heading 2
  Content under heading 1

Content under NOT under heading 2, but at the "root" of the file
```

Comment: No - Org mode documents are strictly hierarchical in that sense.

Comment: @NickD thanks you!